# C# Regex Match text until specific character

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm trying to get a regex to validate/extract from a string all the characters until the first dollar. If the string doesn't have any dollar,it should match the whole string but it doesn't work.

What i tested is:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("12345678$1", "/[^\$]*/");
```

What i expect is to get in match.value => 12345678
If the string passed is for example 123456781 it should return everything.

What is wrong?

Thanks
Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("12345678$1", "([^\\$]+)");
```

extracted string should be group 1.

Comment: Thanks john, worked like a charm. Is what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to escape your `\`:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("12345678$1", "[^\\$]*");
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
match = Regex.Match("123456781", "[^\\$]*");
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Outputs:

```
12345678
123456781
```

---

As pointed out by [dolgsthrasir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4294941/dolgsthrasir) you don't need to escape `$` in your regexp so `"[^$]*"` is fine.

Comment: I don't think he wants to escape the \ . From my understanding of the question he only wants to check for the `$` character. Maybe he falsely thought he'd have to escape this character.

Comment: @Dolgsthrasir you, sir, seems to be goddamn right !

Answer (score 0):

From what I am getting, the expression you are using will match any string which is made up from 0 or more instances of any non `$` character.

You could try something like below:

```
        string sample = "1234578";
        Regex regex = new Regex("(.+?)(\\$|$)");
        if (regex.IsMatch(sample))
        {
            Match match = regex.Match(sample);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
```

Which matches and extracts any numbers up to `$` (denoted as `\\$`) or else, the end of the string (denoted by `$`), which ever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, you can just use `IndexOf` and `SubString`

```
var str = "12345678$1";
int index = str.IndexOf("$");
if(index < 0)
    return str;
else
    return str.Substring(0, index);
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iPFEV2)

Answer (score -2):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("12345678$1", "(.+)\\$");
```

And your result will be in match.Groups[1]

Comment: `all the characters` => not only decimals